# Webpage input element, not URL / Open Site Dialog

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, accessibility, user-experience

I am working on an application that asks individuals to paste links to their social media and other relevant sites as part of the setup process. These later get turned into links on a compiled HTML page.

We are seeing a user issue that is arduous to deal with. When setting up the account on mobile, individuals do not understand that they need the website link to these various places, they try and open the target sites app instead (Facebook as an example), or they stare blankly unsure of what to put in the box or how to proceed.

I'm looking for a solution to this conundrum to help people achieve their ultimate end goal of putting the link on the resultant page.

I tried an iframe approach, whereby the thought was to load the target site, allow the user to navigate to the desired page, and hit a done button. Obviously this approach ran into several road blocks due to security restrictions and frame busting implemented by the various sites.

What would be great would be something like the file input, but for websites instead. We have the "URL" input; however, that only checks the URL for validity, I'm more interested in an approach that would open something akin to the file dialog, that would allow a user to navigate to a site and hit "done"

I've not been able to find anything that comes close. I'm seeing if someone knows something I do not, or has an idea I haven't yet tried. Ultimately, I'm trying to make it easy for an average consumer to choose the target for a link. (I'm fully aware how easy it is to open a browser tab and copy the link, I am truly supporting consumers who find that somewhat difficult / confusing)

Thank you for your time and consideration

Comment: Have you tried approaching a professional about this matter? Because it sounds like you are looking for someone to build a solution for you. I'm afraid Stack Overflow is not meant to help you solve this conundrum. A UX designer and a Frontend Developer are the kind of people to look for. Best of luck on your quest.

Comment: Hello Emiel, I am a developer. I'm not looking for someone to build a solution for me, I'm looking for a technical approach I haven't tried yet. The end goal is allowing an end user to easily select a webpage as the target for a link (webpages that I have no control over). Any viable technique for accomplishing this is welcome. The question is somewhat broad because I have no notion of how to proceed. I've exhausted the ideas I had.